# The execution order of the dart's closure or function

Tags: dart

I was reading about dart functions on this site and I  found interesting example.

One of them is:

```
void main() {
  var y = () {
    print("foo");
    return 10;
  };
  print("bar");
  print(y());
}
```

Which is obvious and I understand. We have assignment of the function to variable y.
And then execution. It will print bar foo 10

But I stumbled on the following example:

```
void main() {
  var x = () {
    print("foo");
    return 10;
  }();
  print("bar");
  print(x);
}
```

It will print foo, then bar then 10

I can't figure it out why....

Comment: `() {print ("foo"); return 10; }` is a function - if you add `()` you are calling that function, so now `foo` is printed and a value of `10` is assigned to `x` variable, than you print `bar` and finally you print `x` (meaning `10`)

Comment: thanks.. () {print ("foo"); return 10; }()  is a function invocation. Never seen it before.

Comment: if for `var y = () {print ("foo"); return 10; }` you can use `y()` then you can also use `() {print ("foo"); return 10; } ()` - but i agree: it looks strange...

Answer (score 0):

This a **Immediately-Invoked Function Expression (IIFE)**

the `()` added after function declaration cases the function to be invoked as long as its declaration found

so this

```
() {  
       print ("foo"); 
       return 10; 
        }();
```

is equal to this

```
x() {  
       print ("foo"); 
       return 10; 
        }
    x();
```

in your code what happened is the function invoked when declared and it prints 'foo', then 10 value is returned to x , then 'bar' is printed , then x is printed which hold 10.

I hope that was clear.

Comment: I got confused with that strange syntax. Now It is clear.

Comment: cool , if that helped upvote and mark question as answered ;)